# node.js equivalent for ActiveRecord's sanitize_sql method

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sql-injection, sanitization

I'm missing the api for ActiveRecord's sanitize_sql method.

Ideally, I'm looking for an api like:

```
sanitizeSql("select * from users where id = ?", [11], function(err, results) {
  ...
});
```

I'm using postgres, but I don't want to use postgres' variable replacement. I want to keep the query building in my app, so I can easily debug & log sql calls in the app.